# Looping date range subset and saving each subset separately

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, subset, date-range

I'm not sure how to subset a df in a loop properly. I can do it individually over each date range, but I'm not quite sure how to loop it. Other questions I've looked at subset by date range, but not multiple ones. If they did subset by multiple date ranges I couldn't get them to work for me.

I have continuous data over three years, but only need data during certain periods over the three years (typically a few days at a time). I have my examples of my continuous data **df** and my event start and end times **eventFile**. All dates are POSIXct.

df

| datetime | Discharge | SSC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2018 0:00 | 61.8 | 8.261706817 |
| 10/1/2018 0:15 | 61.8 | 8.261706817 |
| 10/1/2018 0:30 | 61.8 | 8.261706817 |
| 10/1/2018 0:45 | 60.5 | 8.261706817 |
| 10/1/2018 1:00 | 61.8 | 8.261706817 |
| 10/1/2018 1:15 | 61.8 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 1:30 | 61.8 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 1:45 | 61.8 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 2:00 | 61.8 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 2:15 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 2:30 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 2:45 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 3:00 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 3:15 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 3:30 | 60.5 | 8.105612135 |
| 10/1/2018 3:45 | 60.5 | 7.950911002 |

eventFile

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 10/1/2018 0:15 | 10/1/2018 1:45 |
| 10/1/2018 2:45 | 10/1/2018 3:45 |

This is what I used to pull the info for one event and I want to use for multiple events

```
event1 <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile[1,1]
     & df$datetime <= eventFile[1,2], ]
```

I've tried both below subset the data in a loop, but it's
not working quite right and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.

```
 for (f in length(eventFile)){ 
  x <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile$start[f]
  & df$datetime <= eventFile$end[f], ]

for (f in length(eventFile)){ 
  c <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile[f,1]
          & df$datetime <= eventFile[f,2], ]
```

What I need is to subset each event range into separate data frames. How the script below outputs the data, but with out the repetition.

```
event1 <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile[1,1]
     & df$datetime <= eventFile[1,2], ]
event2 <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile[2,1]
             & df$datetime <= eventFile[2,2], ]
event3 <- df[df$datetime >= eventFile[3,1]
             & df$datetime <= eventFile[3,2], ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a vector of start and end dates per episode:

```
episodes <- c(
    as.Date("2018/01/01"), ## start episode A
    as.Date("2018/01/10"), ## end episode A
    as.Date("2018/03/05"), ## start episode B
    as.Date("2018/03/15")  ## end episode B
)
```

then `findInterval` will return an even number (n `%% 2` = 0 = FALSE) for any date outside the episodes of interest and an odd number (... = TRUE) for dates falling in the episodes:

```
## is 2018/01/11 inside an observation period?
## > findInterval(as.Date("2018/01/11"), episodes) %% 2
## 0
```

... now you can convert your event table **df_event** to an episode vector like:

```
library(dplyr)
episodes <- df %>% as.matrix %>% t %>% as.vector
```

... and tag your dataframe **df** rows like this:

```
df %>%
    mutate(interval = findIntervall(datetime, episodes),
           interval_in_observation_period = interval %% 2
    )
```

... finally you can filter your dataframe to keep only observations during the desired episodes, `group_by` or `split`, depending on taste, and `lapply`, `summarize` (with file saving being your aggregation function) or `purrr::walk` the result.